# Elliptic integrals with parameter outside $0<m<1$

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions

I'm attempting to implement an equation (for calculating [magnetic forces between coils](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TMAG.2010.2049026), eqs (22–24) in the linked paper) that requires the use of elliptic integrals.

Unfortunately these equations require the evaluation of the elliptic integrals far outside their standard parameter range of $0\le m\le 1$ and the numerical implementations I have available to evaluate them give inconsistent results.

I believe that Mathematica is correct in its answer:

```
EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[1/c5]], c5] //. c5 -> 817.327
=> 0.054961 - 1.17196*10^-17 i
```

Whereas Matlab's MuPad engine gives:

```
mfun('EllipticF',asin(sqrt(1/817.327)),sqrt(817.327))
=> 0.054961 - 0.000707i
```

(Mma's function takes parameter $m=k^2$ whereas MuPad takes modulus $k$, explaining the `sqrt`)
While I can use Mathematica for my own work, my colleagues only have Matlab available and I'd like them to be able to use this code.

I'm a pretty unfamiliar with the theory behind elliptic integrals, but [Baker's ‘Elliptic Functions’](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31076.bibrec.html) says

> We shall see later on that the quantity $k^2$ [...] can always be considered real and less than unity.

Which leads me to ask: can the arguments to these elliptic integrals be re-stated in terms of an input of $k>1$, such as I seem to require above?

Comment: ...and if I may make a slightly gauche suggestion, it might be profitable to re-express the whole mess in terms of the [Carlson integrals](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19#PT3), which are less finicky about argument restrictions.

Comment: Lest people become confused with terminology: $k$ is a *modulus*, while $m$ is a *parameter*.

Comment: I had a look at that paper you linked to; a lot of their elliptic integral expressions are a baroque mess, and I suspect they only wrote what *Mathematica* spat out without even pausing to look at what can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge on getting my naming straight. I edited the question slightly to improve my terminology there. Regarding the elliptic integrals, I'm sure you're right unfortunately; I'm actually having some further issues (my question only addresses one term of the equations, as you will have seen in the paper) but I need to get my head straight before I keep asking for help. Thanks again in the mean time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you seem to require here are the so-called ["reciprocal-modulus transformations"](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7#ii).

In your specific case, upon applying the reciprocal-modulus transformation, your elliptic integral can actually be simplified to

$$\frac1{\sqrt{c_5}}F\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\vert \frac1{c_5}\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{c_5}}K\left(\frac1{c_5}\right)$$.

where $K(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind with parameter $m$ (though I understand MuPAD uses $k=\sqrt{m}$ as argument, in which case you seem to know the conversion formulae already).

There are similar formulae for the elliptic integrals of the second and third kinds, and I direct you to the DLMF link I gave above for them.

Comment: For a *Mathematica* demonstration: `With[{c5 = 817.327}, {EllipticK[1/c5]/Sqrt[c5], EllipticF[ArcSin[1/Sqrt[c5]], c5]}] // Chop`

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! This both fixes my Matlab code and makes the equation nicer. One of the downsides of equation derivation by a CAS, I suppose. I suspect there are some more simplifications that can then be made in the overall equation.